# Paperclip image is not storing anywhere (missing.png) rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using **paperclip gem** to upload images but these images are not storing in public folder or anywhere instead it is showing missing.png. I have already specified url, path.

**Model** - This is the model configured with paperclip

```
class AudiModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :exterior_image,

    :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",

    :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename", 

    :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }

    validates_attachment_content_type :exterior_image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

**Contoller**

```
class AudiModelsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_audi_model, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /audi_models
  # GET /audi_models.json
  def index
     @audi_models = AudiModel.all
  end

  # GET /audi_models/1
  # GET /audi_models/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /audi_models/new
  def new
    @audi_model = AudiModel.new
  end

  # GET /audi_models/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /audi_models
  # POST /audi_models.json
  def create
    @audi_model = AudiModel.new(audi_model_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @audi_model.save
         format.html { redirect_to @audi_model, notice: 'Audi model was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @audi_model }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @audi_model.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

   # PATCH/PUT /audi_models/1
   # PATCH/PUT /audi_models/1.json
   def update
     respond_to do |format|
      if @audi_model.update(audi_model_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @audi_model, notice: 'Audi model was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @audi_model }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @audi_model.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /audi_models/1
  # DELETE /audi_models/1.json
  def destroy
    @audi_model.destroy
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to audi_models_url, notice: 'Audi model was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_audi_model
      @audi_model = AudiModel.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
     def audi_model_params
      params.require(:audi_model).permit(:car_model, :variant, :introduction, :engine, :exterior_image, :video, :brochure)
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant controller code and what version of rails you are using?

Comment: rails version is 4.2.5 and above is my controller code. I generated it using scaffold command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it ! path should be like. Need to specify attributte name also in path.

:path => ":rails_root/public/system/exterior_image/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename"